# SQL and PHP - Submit form with an ID in URL (in wordpress)

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, forms

I've been trying to find the best way to do this for a while now but cannot figure it out.

I have a simple dropdown which auto populates based on an SQL query. When you press "search" I need it to go to a page with the url extension `?id=x` where x is the id of the option they selected.

```
$locations = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM wp_places_index WHERE visible='Y' ORDER BY place_name ASC") );
?>
<form id="find-buses-form" method="post" action="places_index.php">
<select class="default-value" type="text" name="from">
<option>Please select...</option>
<?php 
    foreach($locations as $location)
    {
    echo "<option>".$location->place_name."</option>";
  // maybe this?  echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\">".$location->id."</input>";
    }
?>

</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Show me" />   
</form>
```

I think I may need to make it go to an external page which uses $_POST to pull that hidden field but I'd rather do it on one page.

I've achieved this before out of wordpress using something like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                    $picture = $row['Image'];
                    if($picture == ""){
                    $picture= "thumbnails/no-image-small.png";
            }
                    $product_ID = $row["ProductID"];
```

But wordpress does not like the `mysql_fetch_array`  :( Any advise?

Comment: You mentioned Wordpress not liking mysql_fetch_array(), but have you tried mysql_fetch_assoc()?

Comment: I dont think it likes it because i am using
$wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare
as opposed to
mysql_db_query

Comment: isn't your form already going to places_index.php as the external page?   you can write some code in there that redirects the page if the POST variable is set.

Comment: Sorry thats the page i need it to go to with .php?id=x  at the end

Because on that page i got an if statement saying "if id=null - list everything on the page. else - display that particular item

Comment: you must think in terms of HTML. make an HTML form and experiment with it. Only after you get it to work, you can start to build it with some PHP

Comment: My form did work up to the point where it didnt put the ID into the address bar when you click Send. But it is working now, thanks Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put whatever in a `value` attribute of your `option` tag. For example:

```
<?php
$locations = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM wp_places_index WHERE visible='Y' ORDER BY place_name ASC") );
?>
<form action="places_index.php" method="get">
  <select name="x">
<?php foreach ($locations as $location): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $location->id; ?>"><?php echo $location->place_name; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
  </select>
</form>
```

When submitted, the form will go to `http://example.com/places_index.php?x=1` presuming the `name` of your `select` is `x` and the `option` selected has `1` in its `value` attribute.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I thought it might have something to do wiht the value, but I was not sure how to set it up. thanks a lot man

Comment: No problem. Glad to have helped!